# How to say "I am not the person you think I am"

Tags: phrases, idioms

How to say it when:

1. Somebody thinks you are Jack but you are Bob. I know it's wrong if I say "you got me wrong". But what can I say to say you have found a wrong person?
2. Also the same question as above when somebody rings our door bell and we want to say "you have came in to the wrong place and this is not where you think".

Comment: "That's not me, I'm Bob" and "[I think] you have the wrong address"?

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine: Oh I didn't know that. If you think it works for you, please transfer it to that stack, if not, I will ask there again.

Comment: "I'm Bob, not Jack" would suffice. More subtle is the case where your name is indeed Jack, but you reply "I'm not *the Jack* you think I am."

Comment: I usually say for (1) 'I'm afraid you've got me mixed up with someone else', and for (2) 'There's no-one of that name here. You must have the wrong address'.

Comment: "You've mistaken me for someone else" is another good one.  Usually you're confused when someone does it, so you just go "Uh... No;" and then they figure it out from your expression.  Or you can just go, "Wrong guy..."

Comment: "These are not the droids you're looking for" ;)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence

> I am not the person you think I am.

is most often used to mean "you have misunderstood my character", not "You have mistaken my identity." It is used when one person attributes to another characteristics that the second person thinks mistaken, as in:

> *Person A*: You are much too kind to say such a thing.
> *Person B*: I am not the person you think I am.

Often this is used in a gendered version, with "man" or "woman" used in place of "person".

When the intent is to indicate a confusin of identity, ther are many ways to express this, including several metioens inn teh comments to the question:

> - That's not me, I'm Bob.
> - [I think] you have the wrong address.
> - I'm afraid you've got me mixed up with someone else
> - There's no-one of that name here. You must have the wrong address
> - I don't think I know you. I believe that you have he wrong person.
> - **Who** are you looking for?
> - I think you are mistaken.

along with many other possibilities.